# Data appending in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have a requirement to make a function which takes n number of arguments and returns the values in a dictionary data structure.

For example:

Input: it will take arguments in a list

```
list =['a','b','c']
```

this list can go to n number of values.

Output: Function returns the value as

```
{'a':[1,2,'x'],
 'b':[3,4,'y'],
 'c':[5,6,'z']
}
```

I have used python 3.x for the same and tried below code, which gave an error `unhashable type: 'list'`:

```
def Myfunc(*args):
  dir={}
  for x in args:
    lst=[1,2,3] # This list has static value here but in actual code,
                # I am generating some dynamic value. Length of list always 3.
    dir[x]=lst
z=Myfunct(['a','b','c'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to pass a list as in the code below?

Also, please note that your function doesn't return anything.

I changed name of the variable from `dir` to `d`, because `dir` is a built-in python function:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=dir#dir

```
In [31]: def Myfunc(*args):
    ...:   d={}
    ...:   for x in args:
    ...:     lst=[1,2,3] #this list has static value here but in actual code, I am generating some dynamic value. Length of list always 3.
    ...:     d[x]=lst
    ...:   return d
    ...: 

In [32]: z = Myfunc(*['a','b','c'])

In [33]: z
Out[33]: {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

`*args` is meant to be used to pass variable number of arguments to the function. So in your case if you did

```
z = MyFunct('a', 'b', 'c')
```

then it would work as you expected.

You're actually passing just one argument so the for loop is evaluating just once and with `x = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

You should change the declaration to:

```
def MyFunct(arg):
```